# HTTPWebRequest and "X_Session"?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-401

I am new to interacting with a webpage in C#. I have come across a problem where a server returns a 401 unauthorized access exception, even though I provided correct credentials. I have traced the source of my problem to something called an "X_Session" as in below:
[image: X_Session]

[image: X_Session]

How would I generate one of these?

The code I currently have is:

```
    private void snd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        string pnum = number.Text;
        string msg = text.Text;

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.Append("%7B%22contact_value%22%3A%22" + pnum + "%22%2C");
        postData.Append("%22contact_type%22%3A2%2C");
        postData.Append("%22message%22%3A%22" + msg + "%22%2C");
        postData.Append("%22read%22%3A1%2C");
        postData.Append("%22message_direction%22%3A2%2C");
        postData.Append("%22message_type%22%3A1%2C");
        postData.Append("%22date%22%3A%22Sat+Nov+30+2013+13%3A20%3A44+GMT-0800+(Pacific+Standard+Time)%22%2C");
        postData.Append("%22from_name%22%3A%22[redacted name]%22%7D");

        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] byData = encoding.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.textnow.com/api/users/[redacted username]/messages"));
        WebResponse response = null;

        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

        System.Net.NetworkCredential netCredential =
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("[redacted username]", "[redacted password]");
        req.Credentials = netCredential;

        req.PreAuthenticate = true;
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.Method = "OPTIONS";
        req.Host = "www.textnow.com";
        req.Accept = "*/*";
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        req.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Request-Headers","accept, origin, x_session, content-type");
        req.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method","POST");
        response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();


        HttpWebRequest mreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.textnow.com/api/users/csharpautomaton/messages"));
        mreq.Method = "POST";
        mreq.Host = "www.textnow.com";
        mreq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        mreq.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
        mreq.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch");
        mreq.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        mreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
        mreq.Credentials = netCredential;

        mreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

        mreq.Referer = "https://www.textnow.com/api/users/[redacted username]/messages";
        mreq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        mreq.KeepAlive = true;


        mreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

        Stream sw = mreq.GetRequestStream();
        sw.Write(byData,0,byData.Length);
        sw.Close();
        response = (HttpWebResponse)mreq.GetResponse();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who created the X_session value in the sample you posted?

Whoever created that value will know what the rules are for creating it. 
**It was probably setup on some prior request and saved for later use.**

Comment: I checked fiddler, and a new X_Session is generated every time I visit the website. I am pretty sure PHP has something to do with it, those two requests I have in my question are the only two requests that were sent when using a normal web browser.

Comment: Try just creating your own random value? or take that one and modify it.  This is assuming your browser generated that x_session header as a random value and not a hash of some sort of the content or request.

Comment: I tried using a previous session ID, it gave me Error 400, bad request.

Comment: Did you search all their javascript code for references to X_session?

Comment: I found a reference to it in: http://www.textnow.com/assets/js/libs/require.js I will continue searching fiddler for X_Session that has been sent, there appears to be some interaction with cookies.

Comment: Yeah, they are setting the header as a session value in that file. It's set from the id from the login method that is used, e.g. facebook or others.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42541/discussion-between-david-freitas-and-user2396111)